# Create a single item List<string> from a List<object>

Tags: c#, linq

Let's say I have an object that looks like this:

```
private class Group
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public int memberCount { get; set; }
}
```

And then I have a `List<Group>` called `groups`.  But, now what I need is just a list of all of the names.

```
List<string> names = group.???
```

So, just to be clear, if `groups` looks like this:

```
id    name        memberCount
-----------------------------
1,   "Math Club",    24
2,   "Chess Club",   12
3,   "Drama Club",   19
```

Then what I want is a list that looks like this:

```
"Math Club"
"Chess Club"
"Drama Club"
```

Comment: groups.Select(g => g.name)

Comment: for future reference `object` is a class that all other classes inherit from, therefore and you can actually have a `List<object>`, which is not the exact same as a `List<SomeOtherClass>`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just use LINQ:

```
List<string> names = groups.Select(x => x.name).ToList();
```

This will [Select()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) all the names, and turn it into a `List<string>` via [ToList()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 3):

Use LINQ and [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.110).aspx) method:

```
var Names = groups.Select(c => c.name).ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

Non Linq answer

```
List<string> names = new List<string>();
foreach(var group in groups)
{
    names.Add(group.name);
}
```